# Get CPU Temperature using Open Hardware Monitor

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

I am trying to use the OpenHardwareMonitorLib DLL to get the temperature of my CPU \ cores, however this doesn't return the temperature for me.

I have looked around and seen that this is a problem almost everywhere but I cannot get this to work.

I would be very appreciative if someone can tell me where I am going wrong with this.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Collections;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;


namespace cs_TempReader
{
    class Program
    {
        private DateTime now;
        protected readonly ListSet<ISensor> active = new ListSet<ISensor>();
        public event SensorEventHandler SensorAdded;
        public event SensorEventHandler SensorRemoved;

        protected virtual void ActivateSensor(ISensor sensor)
        {
            if (active.Add(sensor))
                if (SensorAdded != null)
                    SensorAdded(sensor);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myComputer = new Computer();

            myComputer.CPUEnabled = true;
            myComputer.ToCode();
            myComputer.Open();

            foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
            {
                hardwareItem.Update();
                hardwareItem.GetReport();

                Console.WriteLine(hardwareItem.GetReport());

                var series = new LineSeries();

                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", sensor.Name, sensor.Hardware, sensor.SensorType, sensor.Value);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to tie this into a bigger application.

Comment: Does the OHM app work correctly?

Comment: Looking through some of the other OpenHardwareMonitor tagged questions, I came across [Recent OpenHardwareMonitor Sample Code C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765192/recent-openhardwaremonitor-sample-code-c-sharp?rq=1) and one of the answers suggests that you need to run VS with admin privileges due to the nature of the API calls.

Comment: @Simon: The editor was correct to remove your signature from the question, as your user name is automatically displayed at the lower right of the question by SO itself.

Comment: thank you!

I could have had this wrapped up yesterday if i had just done that.... 

I guess the application that this will go into will also need the rights elevating too.

Comment: I'm just going to upvote this from the sheer novelty of the effort. Sounds cool!

Answer (score 3):

You need to request a higher execution level in the application so this code can work properly.

To do this you have to:

- Right click on the project;
- Click on **Add**
- Click on **New Item...**
- Type **manifest** on the search bar
- Click on **Ok**

After that you have to change this line on the manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

To this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```